# Autocomplete not working with result have quotation mark(") or apostrophe(')

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

Here is my jquery file for the autocomplete[1.autocomplete.js](http://www.ninenik.com/demo/autocomplete.js) , cascading style sheet
[2.autocomplete.css](http://www.ninenik.com/demo/autocomplete.css) and picture magnifier
[3.autocomplete.gif](http://www.ninenik.com/demo/autocomplete.gif)

HTML & JavaScript Code:

```
<input type = 'textbox' id='vendor' name = 'vendor' maxlength='70'>
<input name="h_vendor" type="hidden" id="h_vendor" value=""/>

function make_autocom(autoObj,showObj){
    var mkAutoObj=autoObj; 
    var mkSerValObj=showObj; 
    new Autocomplete(mkAutoObj, function() {
        this.setValue = function(id) {      
            document.getElementById(mkSerValObj).value = id;
        }
        if ( this.isModified )
            this.setValue("");
        if ( this.value.length < 1 && this.isNotClick ) 
            return ;    
        return "auto_vendor.php?q=" +encodeURIComponent(this.value);
    }); 
}
make_autocom("vendor","h_vendor");
```

File auto_vendor.php:

```
$q = urldecode($_GET["q"]);
$pagesize = 5; 
$table_db="buy"; 
$find_field="vendor"; 
$sql = "select distinct vendor from $table_db  where locate('$p', $find_field) > 0 and division = \"".$_SESSION['chk_division']."\" order by locate('$p', $find_field), $find_field limit $pagesize";
$results = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $results )) {
    $id = $row["vendor"]; 
    $name = $row["vendor"]; 
    $name = str_replace("'", "'", $name);
    if($q!=""){
        $display_name = preg_replace("?(" . $q . ")?i", "<b>$1</b>", $name); 
    }else{
        $display_name = $name;
    }
    echo "<li onselect=\"this.setText('$name').setValue('$id');\">$display_name</li>";
}
```

While have result with (")or(') autocomplete can't get result to textbox.

http://resource.thaicreate.com/upload/stock/20151117044401.jpg?v=1001

Comment: Okay, it looks like this is because `$id` contains a string with the quotes, it is ending the string param for your JS (or HTML attribute depending on the quote used) and causing an error.

Comment: @JonStirling How to fix it. I'm a newbie.

Comment: You _might_ be able to get away with using [addslashes](http://php.net/addslashes) on your $id and $name variables. But I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @Jon Stirling Can't fix it. Thank for your answer.